# SQL: querying primary key coloumn for condition to "where col is NULL"

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

How sql engine process a query when some one hit the db with a query like

```
select * from table where primary_key_col is NULL
```

since primary key coloumn can't have null, will it straight away return empty rows or it tries to hit the index to search

Comment: It won't return "empty rows"; it will return "Empty set", that is, it will return "no rows".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`primary_key_col=NULL` cant be used since you can not compare null using = operator, you need to use `is null`

```
select * from table where primary_key_col is null
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/working-with-null.html

UPDATE : I misquoted the question

> since primary key coloumn can't have null, will it straight away
>   return empty rows or it tries to hit the index to search

This could ne explained with the following explain query. I have a table `users` and `idusers` is the PK auto-incremented (mysql 5.6)

Now lets run an explain and see

```
mysql> explain select * from users where idusers is null ;
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra            |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | NULL  | NULL | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | NULL | Impossible WHERE |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+------------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

Where you can see that it gives you `impossible where`
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/explain-output.html

> MySQL has read all const (and system) tables and notice that the WHERE
>   clause is always false.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/explain-output.html#jointype_const

So your index table may not be even scanned by the optimizer after it fails on the first place.